# Dual login Windows and OSX on an Apple computer (not dual boot)

Tags: macos, windows, login-screen

A couple years ago I was using the business center of an Embassy Suites hotel. They had Apple computers with a dual login screen where I could choose to login to Windows or OSX. This was not a dual boot setup. It was choose at login. I have not been able to find a system that does this.

Do you know of such a system that makes this possible? Again, this is for a dual login, not a dual boot configuration.

Comment: What user name and password did it ask for?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it was more about how much money you paid to get minutes on the computer not a username and password. It was like 20 bucks for 10 minutes or something ridiculous like that. The reason I ask about this at all is because I'm trying to decide how to best equip an Apple computer lab for multi purpose computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact system. It was enabled by [Boot Runner](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it was a dual boot set up. This can be done via refit and would show a screen like [this](http://refit.sourceforge.net/screen.html)

You then get taken to the Windows or OS X login - but for both of these you can make this auto login so the process does not stop here and you go in as a user. In OS X probably as the guest user and I think this can be done on windows as well

Comment: This sounds more like it. Maybe it was a dual boot and the login step as you describe it sounds like what I saw.

Comment: At that screen, if you were to select Windows, you would see the entire boot process and 'starting windows' screen etc... right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless Parallels Coherence is used. Parallels runs Windows Apps in Mac. Find out more here -- http://kb.parallels.com/en/4670

Comment: The environment as I witnessed it segregated the operating systems. It was not Parallels.